# Why don't fedora 38 proxy settings work with Firefox "Use system proxy configuration"?

Tags: proxy, fedora

I have tried on kde, gnome, and cinnamon, and none of them allow Firefox to use the proxy set in system settings (in my case I was attempting to use a socks proxy). Instead of connecting through the proxy it connects as though the "no proxy" option was set. This is kind of annoying, and I know that the proxy settings work on debian-based systems, and I wonder if anyone else has this problem, and if it can be remedied?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I guess it because of fedora firewall blocks that,
specially when your proxy is working with ipv6

try this:

```
sudo systemctl stop firewalld.service
```